# Python Object attribute search mechanism

Tags: python

As per [this article](http://www.cafepy.com/article/python_attributes_and_methods/python_attributes_and_methods.html)

> When accessed objectname.attributename, the following objects are searched in sequence for the attribute:

1.
The object itself (`objectname.__dict__` or any Python-provided attribute of objectname).

2.
The object's type (`objectname.__class__.__dict__`). Observe that only `__dict__` is searched, which means only user-provided attributes of the class. In other words `objectname.__bases__` may not return anything even though `objectname.__class__.__bases__` does exist.

3.
The bases of the object's class, their bases, and so on. (`__dict__` of each of `objectname.__class__.__bases__`). More than one base does not confuse Python, and should not concern us at the moment. The point to note is that all bases are searched until an attribute is found.

To test the theory I created this example

```
class Superb(object):
    svar=1

class Sub(Superb):
    ...

class Leaf(Sub):
    def __init__(self):
        print(Leaf.svar)

lobj=Leaf()
```

The instance creation worked and printed the value of Leaf.svar (as 1). 
This means that when resolving Leaf.svar, Python looked at the *base of the base of the Leaf object*, which is not something mentioned in the article. As per the article, *bases of the object's class* (i.e. type) are searched . I doubt that the article writer made any mistake it's most certainly a gap in my understanding. Can someone please clarify.

Comment: "The bases of the object's class, **their bases**, and so on"

Comment: The base of the object's (Leaf) class here is 'type' it's base is 'object' -> This path of search doesn't go thru Sub (Leaf's base) and Superb (Sub's base)

Comment: No, Leaf's `bases` are `(Sub,`). Try `print(Leaf.__bases__)`. How did you get `type`?

Comment: You are right base of Leaf is Sub, but Sub is NOT the base of the objec's class (Which is type in this case). The article says that the variable is searched in the base of object's class (not the base of the object). May be its just me who is reading it differently

Comment: @PavelAnossov What OP is saying is that "the object" here is the class `Leaf`. And that's true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if it's fair to answer your own question but with some further reading I understood that when the object is 'class' then there is a slight modification in the rule. So in case of class.attribute the bases of the class are also searched (along with the class of the class i.e. type).

class.attribute should therefore be searched in

> Object attributes (i.e. class definition)
>
> Bases of object (classname.**__*bases*__** and so on)
>
> Object's type ('type' in case of class)
>
> Base of object's class (i.e. object)

Comment: It's fair to answer it (sometimes necessary if nobody else is seriously looking into it), however, you don't get reputation for it.  See [Etiquette for answering your own question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17845/etiquette-for-answering-your-own-question) in Meta.

Answer (score 4):

The article glosses over some details. When you have questions like this, it's time to turn to an authoritative source, which in this case is The Python Language Reference, section [3.2. The standard type hierarchy](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#the-standard-type-hierarchy), which contains an entry for classes which states (my emphasis):

> A class has a namespace implemented by a dictionary object. Class attribute references are translated to lookups in this dictionary, e.g., `C.x` is translated to `C.__dict__["x"]` (although for new-style classes in particular there are a number of hooks which allow for other means of locating attributes). **When the attribute name is not found there, the attribute search continues in the base classes**.

This is describing attribute lookup for classes, not class instances, and i believe it explains what is happening in your code.

For completeness, here's what the next entry, about class instances, says:

> A class instance has a namespace implemented as a dictionary which is the first place in which attribute references are searched. When an attribute is not found there, and the instance’s class has an attribute by that name, the search continues with the class attributes.

I take "the search continues with the class attributes" as meaning "repeat the procedure given for classes", ie search the base classes. Inheritance would be rather less useful if it didn't!

The article you link to explains attribute lookup for class instances, but it doesn't say anything about attribute lookup for classes. Because it doesn't, it gives the impression that it works the same way, which is not the case.

Comment: Tom thanks for looking at this question, may be I am reading (understanding it incorrectly) but this is what the line in article means. Bases of the Object (Leaf in this example) is 'type' and it's base is 'object' which doesn't have any further base class. Superb in this case is not the base of object's class or the base of base of object's class, it's the base of the base of the object itself.

Comment: @AccEnq: You're absolutely right. I actually misread your question, and thought you were talking about attribute lookup in a class instance. That was careless of me - my apologies. I have rewritten the answer to refer to the Python language reference, which explains this.